# C# trying to simplify Generic Extension Function for Generic Typed Interface

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

Here is the code, last line is the highlight of what I am doing:

```
public interface IHasContext<TContext> {
  TContext Context {get; set;}
}
public static class Extensions {
  public static void ProcessContext<THasContext, TContext>(this THasContext t)
    where THasContext : IHasContext<TContext> 
    where TContext : class {
      //...
  }
}
public class SomeClassContext {/*...*/}
public class SomeClass : IHasContext<SomeClassContext> { 
  public SomeClassContext Context {get; set;}
  //...
}

//now in a function I can do:
  objSomeClass.ProcessContext<SomeClass, SomeClassContext>();
```

You see, because `SomeClass` already knows it contains `<SomeClassContext>`, so I want to do:

```
  objSomeClass.ProcessContext();
```

without the `<SomeClass, SomeClassContext>` chunk. Is it possible? How should I alter my code to achieve it? Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you need two generic parameters. Just use one:

```
public static class Extensions {
  public static void ProcessContext<TContext>(this IHasContext<TContext> t)
    where TContext : class {
    //...
  }
}
```

Then inference should work just fine:

```
var obj = new SomeClass();
obj.ProcessContext();
```

There is one slight semantic difference between the two. If the type `SomeClass` was a `struct` then your version would not box the argument `t`, while this version will causing boxing.

Comment: Oh! thanks! I couldn't wrap my head around the idea. Thanks for your help!